# Passing props to other Page Component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

Hello I have a purchase history that whenever I click that purchase it will go to another component where it will show more details of the purchase.

This is the new page that I want to show whenever I click an item

```
import React from "react"

const PurchaseHistoryItem = ({ history }) => {
  console.log(history.shop.name)
  return (
    <>
      <p>test</p>
    </>
  )
}

export default PurchaseHistoryItem
```

and this is where I fetch the props from

```
const PurchaseHistoryPage = (props) => {


const classes = useStyles()

  const [history, setHistory] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const user = getUser()
    getPurchaseHistory(
      "/user/list/purchase-history/" + user.userId,
      user.token
    ).then((data) => {
      setHistory(
        data.map((history) => {
          return <PurchaseHistory key={history._id} history={history} />
        })
      )
    })
  }, [])
  return (
    <>
<Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={2}>
          <Box pt={0.5}>
            <Link to="/user">
              <ArrowBackIcon className={classes.backSize} />
            </Link>
          </Box>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={10}>
          <Typography variant="h6">Purchase History</Typography>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Box pt={5}></Box>
      <div>{history}</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

but I can't seem to pass props to the purchasehistoryitem page.

INDex PAGE on how I call the page

```
<PurchaseHistoryItem path="user/history/:id" />
```

and this is how I go to the PurchaseHistoryItem Page

```
<Link to={history._id} className={classes.decoration}>
```

Comment: "_but I can't seem to pass props to the purchasehistoryitem page._"

Why? what is the error?

Comment: You only passed the props in the child component function, you didn't specify where you want to use it

Comment: const PurchaseHistoryItem = ({ history }) => {
  console.log(history.shop.name)
  return (
    <>
      <p>{history}</p> you didn't pass it here. Text is not meant to be here
    </>
  )
}

Comment: @Phemieny007 this is an answer rather than a comment, would you mind posting that as an answer?

Comment: I'm getting cannot read property shop of undefined. @SinanYaman

Comment: Where do you use `<PurchaseHistoryItem />` ?

Comment: I'm using it for a new page when I click an item. @SinanYaman

Comment: Where, in the code, do you render `<PurchaseHistoryItem />`

Comment: on the <PurchaseHistoryPage /> there is no <PurchaseHistoryItem /> @SinanYaman

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234096/discussion-between-pinky-promise-and-sinan-yaman).

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the props to the component first:

in PurchaseHistoryPage:

```
import PurchaseHistoryItem from '~path-to-PurchaseHistoryItem'
...

return (
    <>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={2}>
          <Box pt={0.5}>
            <Link to="/user">
              <ArrowBackIcon className={classes.backSize} />
            </Link>
          </Box>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={10}>
          <Typography variant="h6">Purchase History</Typography>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Box pt={5}></Box>
      <PurchaseHistoryItem history={history} />
    </>
)
```

Comment: this is the purchase history page. https://imgur.com/feLPvtY when I click an item I want them to be like this per item. https://imgur.com/VYXEAAz. that's why I'm trying to pass the props to <PurchaseHistoryItem/>

Comment: You have to import `PurchaseHistoryItem` somewhere and pass the `history` prop to it. Unless you can show me where you use `PurchaseHistoryItem` in the code like the example in my answer, I won't be able to help you

Comment: but I don't want to render the <PurchaseHistoryItem /> on the PurchaseHistoryPage because I will only show PurchaseHistoryItem page when I click an item

Answer (score 0):

you only passed the props in the child component function, you didn't specify where it is to be used...

```
import React from "react"

const PurchaseHistoryItem = ({ history }) => {
  console.log(history.shop.name)
  return (
    <>
      <p>{history}</p>
    </>
  )
}
```

Here is the parent component

```
import PurchaseHistoryItem from '~path-to-PurchaseHistoryItem'

 const[histroy, setHistroy] = React.useState([])
 
  React.useEffect(() => {
  async function getHistroy() {
    setHistory(list.map(({ ... }) => ({key: ..., name: ...})));
  }
  getHistroy();
}, []);

return (
    
    <>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={2}>
          <Box pt={0.5}>
            <Link to="/user">
              <ArrowBackIcon className={classes.backSize} />
            </Link>
          </Box>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={10}>
          <Typography variant="h6">Purchase History</Typography>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Box pt={5}></Box>
      <PurchaseHistoryItem history={history} />
    </>
)
```

Comment: I'm getting error  'histroy' is not defined  no-undef.

Comment: I thought you were pointing out something else :) I don't think this is the issue

Comment: it a typo error, check it out now, it should work.

Comment: @Phemieny007 nothing shows and I get PurchaseHistoryItem.js:4 undefined

Comment: the error you seeing is beyond the scope of your question an i noticed the way you handled the history state is kinda wrong. will help check it out now

Comment: @SinanYaman have done already showed the right way in his answer.